# npm ERR! FetchError at ClientRequest on ng new app

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to create a new application with the ng new app command.

It goes very fast until the last CREATE message below.

Then it stays for hours (literally) in the "Installing packages (npm)..." message.

Then stops with the error as follows.

Angular CLI: 15.1.5

Node: 18.15.0

```
C:\>cd C:\Applications\vscode-MyAppFrontEnd\MyAppFrontEnd

C:\Applications\vscode-MyAppFrontEnd\MyAppFrontEnd>ng new MyAppFrontEnd
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? SCSS   [ https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#scss
 ]
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/angular.json (2957 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/package.json (1056 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/README.md (1076 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/tsconfig.json (901 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/.gitignore (548 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/tsconfig.app.json (263 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/tsconfig.spec.json (273 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/.vscode/extensions.json (130 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/.vscode/launch.json (474 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/.vscode/tasks.json (938 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/index.html (308 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/main.ts (214 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/styles.scss (80 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/app/app.component.html (23115 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1121 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/app/app.component.ts (227 bytes)
CREATE MyAppFrontEnd/src/app/app.component.scss (0 bytes)
| Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-coverage failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:54321npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at onerror (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:117:21)
npm ERR!     at callbackError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:136:17)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-coverage failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:54321
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at onerror (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:117:21)
npm ERR!     at callbackError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:136:17)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '::1',
npm ERR!   port: xxxxx,
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   requiredBy: '.'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-06T00_41_17_918Z-debug-0.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Angular problem but an npm problem.
Looking at the error

```
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-coverage
```

it seems you have an issue accessing https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-coverage.
Can you click on the link and see something?

If you are in a corporate environment, you might have a proxy issue, as reported in the error message:

```
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

In that case, you might have some proxy file in your Angular app (maybe proxy.conf.js or similar). Make sure you set your proxy configurations according to your organization's rules.

Comment: could it be the Angular and node.js version? Which version would be recommended?

Comment: If I access ```https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-coverage``` in a browser, it opens instantly displaying a json with lots of data. The issue happens in a corp computer which does have corp security and proxy. But it also happens in a personal computer that has just a plain Windows installation with no additional security or proxy software configured. The only difference is that in the personal computer the url error is different: ```FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular```. This other link also opens fine in the browser displaying the json.

Comment: Didn't find a proxy.conf.js file or similar in the Angular app folder. The ```ng new app``` command I'm trying to execute here is exactly to create the app folder. So the only files in there are the ones that could be created during this process that is stopping with an error.

Comment: Without more context it is hard to debug. Can you check other repositories and apps and see whether they use some proxy?

Comment: I changed Node and Angular version to an older one and it worked. Seems it's a problem with these newer versions I was using. Did you try with these and worked for you?